# Headers for every value of parent group ssrs 2008 r2

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2, row, rowheader

I am having output like this in ssrs 2008 R2
        E

```
R   A   T   V
A   A1  6448    11012   (41.4 %)
    A2  363 598 (39.2 %)
    A3  331 715 (53.7 %)
    Total   9405    17486   (46.2 %)
B   B1  6448    11012   (41.4 %)
    B2  363 598 (39.2 %)
    B3  331 715 (53.7 %)
    Total   9405    17486   (46.2 %)
```

But I want my header to repeat for every parent group
Thanks
Amit

Comment: Have you tried inserting a row into your table with the headers?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the header row part of the row group that groups on "R".

This will make that header row repeat with every value for "R".

[image: This is an image]